# Self-compiled kernel doesn't start (fails to find /dev/mapper root volume)

Tags: kernel, lvm, initramfs

I have Ubuntu system (19.10) with default kernel, everything works fine, but sometimes the system slows down.

So I decided to comile my own kernel (like I do on my laptop with debian). I copied config from ubuntu kernel (5.3.x) to the new 5.5.3 and tuned the options a bit, removed unneeded ones.

I have /dev/mapper (lvm?) configured there.

And now I end up with an initramfs that fails to boot that new kernel, it fails because it can't find root fs:

```
Volume group "lpstm" not found
Cannot process volume group lpstm
```

In the initramfs shell when I do ls /dev/mapper I see only "control" file there, there are no entries for root and home.

What happened? What could cause such state? Am I missing some modules? I checked and I have all "DM" modules that are in the default ubuntu kernel.

EDIT:

`lvm lvs` outputs nothing, same with `lvm pvs`.

Comment: Suggest: 1.) install the [mainline PPA kernel 5.5.3](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5.3/); 2.) does it work?; if yes. 3.) take its config file, but do not make any changes yet and compile your own kernel; 4.) does it work?; 5.) do your changes and go from there. Always prove your own compiled kernel works without any changes before making any.

Comment: I also was thinking generic kernel is the cause of performance issue. I've downloaded xanmode kernel, reduced it size and recompiled. But it actually have not improved performance sensibly. I've upgraded my lenovo G550 CPU. And also, you could use `openbox` desktop environment and `plank` dock if you need more performance in some cases.

Comment: @Gryu I'm already using lightweight window manager (Xmonad), the performance issues appear sometimes when either the disk IO is high or cpu usage is high - mouse suddently stops moving or jumps. I don't have such issues on my laptop which is similar performance wise but there I have kernel configured by myself (1000 HZ might be helping there, ubuntu is 250 Hz).

Comment: @DougSmythies Yes, that makes sense, I'll try it the way you described.

Comment: If you want a 1000 Hz kernel, then take the "lowlatency" version from my previous link. Myself, and with the way CPUs now can go into deep idle states for up to 4 seconds at a time, I no longer understand why there even is a 250 Hz kernel anymore.